# Editing a post - minor mistake

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits

I suggested an edit for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38743875/1544364) post.

All I wanted is to correct a mistake by adding `"dependencies": [ "my-target" ]` before `"copies"` in the second code section. This would have handled the use case when the second target is called before the first one (in this case the solution wouldn't have worked as expected).

However, my edit request has been declined twice (as it has been stated, I should have put it as a separate answer or as a comment).

Now, I am really confused here: according to the official [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), minor mistakes should be fixed by edits and it certainly looks like a minor mistake to me.

Moreover, this code section was originally added by myself, so it feels ridiculous trying to explain to the author of the post what is the mistake and convincing him to fix it.

I could have edited my original answer by copy-pasting this post and adding a fix for the mistake, but it just feels wrong: the author provided a very good solution except for a few nuances and he should get all the credit for it.

So what am I supposed to do in such a case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually code edits are declined because not a single reviewer can understand the implications of the edit you make. Hence, you should have commented and explained why the author should change the code in the answer.

> Moreover, this code section was originally added by myself...

Okay, that would make this a legitimate edit... but who knows that? Only those users who go check the revision history or the 'edited by' before checking the edit made. There are not a lot of reviewers who take that much time.

What you should have done (and maybe you did, but we can't know that) is put in the edit summary that you were the author of the original code and that this is a fix to your code formerly approved. That would usually be enough for reviewers to approve your edit, even if they can't validate the code itself.

Comment: I'll give it a try and we'll see if it helps. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: An additional comment would draw extra attention for reviewers too.

Comment: Well, eventually it was approved by the author, so I can't be sure if this tactics works. I did receive one approval before the author's one though, so let's agree that referencing the revision history in edit comment does help. Accepted.